# how to decode encoded IDs using vinkla hashids in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to decode my user id(already encoded ) using vinkla hashids

```
$user_id= "1"; // I encoded this
$en_user_id = Hashids::encode($user_id);      // I got 'ND' 
$dec_user_id = Hashids::decode($en_user_id);  // It is not decoding
```

I want to decode ND to get original ID
when I try to decode I got this

```
ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$en_user_id` is indeed an array?

Comment: echo var_dump($en_user_id); //  string(2) "ND"

Comment: The question was rhetorical. Your exception error is telling you the 1st param is an array.

Comment: Decode actually returns an array 
e.g 
`$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3); // o2fXhV`
`$numbers = $hashids->decode($id); // [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: A good look at the docs, https://github.com/vinkla/hashids will give you some hints

Comment: @Nikhil Do you want to decode only one value???

Comment: So I guess the matter is when does `htmlspecialchars()` come into play? Its not in the question's source code.